# Is there a way to calculate a ratio using SUMIFs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am trying to get cell `I13` on sheet `MONTHLY STATS - SPREADS` to populate a `0` if there have been no `L`'s to count between the dates of 1 Oct 21 and 31 Oct 21 on sheet `SPREADS LOG`.

But I only want this `0` to populate if there is data present in cell `H13`. If there is no data in `H13`I would like `I13` to be blank. (note I cannot use a number format to hide these `0`'s in cell `I13` as I am trying to average the complete `I` column )

Whilst it is doing this cell `I13` must also be able to run the `COUNTIFS` & `SUM` formulas shown below.

This is the current formula in cell `I13` :

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!P:P,{"L"},'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,">="&DATE(2021,10,1),'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,"<="&DATE(2021,10,31)))=0,"",SUM(COUNTIFS('SPREADS LOG'!P:P,{"L"},'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,">="&DATE(2021,10,1),'SPREADS LOG'!R:R,"<="&DATE(2021,10,31))))`

If someone could tweak this formula, that would be great.

[image]

Comment: Side note: the `SUM`s are superfluous. Don't use `SUM` if you're only passing it one argument.

Comment: Always post some sample data with explanation which may be useful to get help.

Comment: @Harun24HR sure, I will edit the question and include a set of sample data.

Comment: @BigBen any suggestions on how to solve this?